# Using if function to get a value from a start date and end date

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup

I am working with Excel, I have two a dataset where I have daily data i.e date broken down by day. I have another dataset that has data by weeks as in start week and end week and I also have a week number to it. I need to extract that "week_number" into my main dataset which is broken down by daily data. start week and end week will have a range of dates in it i.e week start 1/11, week end 1/16 week number 3. I need that week number for my daily data.

I tried using nested ifs but I am trying to look it up in an array so the end result is "spilling"
Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Example

```
Table 1                       Table 2

date                            week_start    week_end   week_number
1/1                                 1/11         1/16      3
1/2
1/3
1/4
```

End result

```
date     week_number
    
1/11         3
1/12         3
```

Comment: To extract the "week_number" into your main dataset based on a start week and end week range, you can use the IF function combined with the AND function to check whether a given date falls within the range of the start week and end week. Here's an example formula you can use:
`=IF(AND(date>=week_start,date<=week_end),week_number,"")`

Comment: I would use SUMIFS(): `=SUMIFS(table2[week_number],table1[date],">="&table2[week_start],table1[date],"<="&table2[week_end])`

Comment: @ScottCraner - won't handle weekends unfortunately;

Comment: @megaultron this will return 0s I'm afraid - unless you compare *last* friday with *next* monday (the way you've presented the [otherwise perfectly valid] point is by having the Mon/Fri that belong to a common / same week - no date will fall after this Friday, but before last Mon (unless you're MJ Fox ☺). jokes

Answer (score 2):

[Exhibit](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9htZHrbLl2blFQzyhKg?e=obcM5G)/screenshot(s) etc. refer:

---

**1. Simplest**

```
=WEEKNUM(C5)-($K$5-$J$5)
```

[image: simplest illustration]

- Leverage native 'weeknum' formula (with adjustment for any misalignment between your/Bill's 'first day of year'
- No spill! worries
- Simple/parsimonious

*Drawbacks / counters*

- Your weeks may differ from Excel in some way/form fashion
- However, the situation regarding '17' vs '3' in my example above is easily allowed for (so your first week might be in the middle of August - corresponding to when you launched a company/project etc .- that doesn't adversely impact anything as I demonstrate above; even if you are modelling 5 day 'working days' vs 7 'calendar' days comprising a week, this does not present an issue; nor does using 7 days;
- Due to `weeknum` function limitations, spill functionality not available (was not clear from Q whether this was desirable or otherwise, notwithstanding - spill# cannot be achieved with this function in its currnt form
- Requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel (not an issue for OP given reference to '`spill`' feature)

---

**2. 'In-betweeny' approach**

(i.e. in btwn other two RE: complexity/parsimony etc.)

```
=LET(a_,$H$5:$H$15,b_,$I$5:$I$15,x_,(C5<=b_)*(C5>=a_),y_,(C5>b_)*(C5<OFFSET(a_,1,0)),z_,SUM($J$5:$J$15*(x_+y_)),z_)
```

[image: in-betweeny]

*Here: x_ takes care of weekdays, y_ takes care of weekends (if your weeks span calendar week/ 7 days, fn still works - per below; akin to what others have proposed RE: `sumifs` [but more concise I'd argue as the conditions equate the product of the same criteria within a `sumifs` - same goes for 'sumproduct' vs 'sum' albeit `sumifs` will provide for 'spill' functionality - which is impossible to achieve with `sum` (or `min`,`max`, `or` - same thing applies btw)]*

- x_ variable caters for working days (assuming weeks span Mon-Fri, albeit this is not pre-requisite,
- function capable of handling non-contiguous week numbers (e.g. if project is suspended for a year after the 2nd 'week', then it shall remain in that status 'weeknum=2' until project is resurrected, at which point it will reflect `weeknum` = 3 (or whatever week num is assigned to it at that point)
- Same goes for working days/weekends, e.g. if you want `weeknum` to reflect next to Sat/Sun, but the table with `weeknum`s exclude weekends, then you can either 'return 'blank' RE: `weeknum`, or decide to assign to previous/next 'workday-week'
- I've assumed these get assigned to the following `weeknum` (e.g. Sat after week 1 picks up week num 2). The project will then continue latest status RE: `weeknum` during this non-contiguous period between (but can leave as is and get on with something else not too far away - (disclaimer - at your own peril! ☺)

---

**Solution 3 (complex - relative context ☺)**

```
=LET(
x_,SORT(VSTACK(H5:H15,I5:I15)),
x2_,HSTACK(x_,INDEX(J5:J15,IFERROR(MATCH(x_,H5:H15,0),MATCH(x_,I5:I15,0)))),
x2a_,INDEX(x2_,0,1),
x2b_,INDEX(x2_,0,2),
z_,IFERROR(INDEX(x2b_,MATCH(C5#,x2a_,1)),TREND(x2b_,x2a_,C5#)),
z_)
```

[image: Meatier version]

---

*Notes:*

- Uses spill# (more robust, efficient) (although this can easily be 'turned off' - although prefer it as is
- It creates a pivot-like view of the sheet with summary/week numbers, then using the nifty parameter '-1' in an otherwise boiler-plate index/match variation to identify lookups

*Overall notes*

- Correspondence between 3 independent methods (and vs manual inspection) hopefully serves to corroborate verisimilitude of results - ta.

---